# Array de numeros com quantidade variavel Java Android

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo um programa para Android e quero fazer um Array de inteiros, porem necesito definir a quandidade de numeros com uma variavel que tem 3 opcoes de valores: 20, 50 e 100.
Tentei usar o codigo abaixo:

```
private int[] listNumbers1 = new int[maxNumber];

    for (int number=0; number<maxNumber; number++) {

    listNumbers1[number] = number+1;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu código só vai apresentar problemas dependendo de onde você posicionar a variável `listNumbers1`.

Basicamente, você precisa posicioná-la no escopo de classe, se caso quiser manter o modificador de acesso `private`, e também pode colocá-la em um método, mas já não poderia usar o modificador `private`, já que ela agora pertence ao método.

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {

    private int[] listNumbers1; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        // super....

        int maxNumbers = 50; // Inicialize a variável aqui
        listNumbers1 = new int[maxNumbers]; // crie sua lista utilizando a referência da variável maxNumbers... que já foi inicializada

        for (int number = 0; number < maxNumbers ; number++) {
            listNumbers1[number] = number+1;
        }
    }
}
```

O código acima deve funcionar normalmente. Você também pode criar a lista `listNumbers1` dentro do método **onCreate**(), se caso preferir que ela seja local. Mas lembre-se que, neste caso, a keyword `private` deve ser removida.

Comment: Vou verificar se resolve, o mais estranho é que esta dando um erro nessa parte do codigo "number < maxNumber; number++" diz que maxNumber e number++ sao classes vazias, mas eles sao variaveis!

Comment: acredito que tenha sido pq eu coloquei como maxNumber ao invés de maxNumbers... errei ao digitar o codigo